# Data-set manipulation to find temp difference in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, dataset

I have the following data-set:

```
oxford, 20180101, tempmax, 140
oxford, 20180101, tempmin, 40
oxford, 20180102, tempmax, 160
oxford, 20180102, tempmin, 20
oxford, 20180103, tempmax, 90
oxford, 20180103, tempmin, 10
oxford, 20180104, tempmax, 200
oxford, 20180104, tempmin, 120
```

How can I read this file in, combine by location and date, and work out the temp difference in python?

example output:

```
oxford, 20180101, tdiff, 40
oxford, 20180102, tdiff, 160
oxford, 20180103, tdiff, 80
oxford, 20180104, tdiff, 80
```

What sort of manipulation in python could be used for this?

Comment: This is too broad, can you narrow it down? Have you done any research, tried anything?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html reshape your data frame first, and then make a new column `tdiff = tempmax - tempmin`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["oxford","oxford","oxford","oxford","oxford","oxford","oxford","oxford"],
                   "B":["20180101","20180101","20180102","20180102","20180103","20180103","20180104","20180104"],
                    "C":["tempmax","tempmin","tempmax","tempmin","tempmax","tempmin","tempmax","tempmin"],
                    "D":[140,40,160,20,90,10,200,120]})


df["B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"])
dfnew = df.sort_values(["B"]).groupby(['A', 'B'])["D"].apply(lambda x: (max(list(x))-min(list(x)))).reset_index()
dfnew["diff"] = "tdiff"


//output

        A          B    D   diff
0  oxford 2018-01-01  100  tdiff
1  oxford 2018-01-02  140  tdiff
2  oxford 2018-01-03   80  tdiff
3  oxford 2018-01-04   80  tdiff
```